# Groovy Method to combine list of lists

Tags: list, groovy

```
Input >> list = [[1,2,3], [6], [3,4,5,6]]

Output >> [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6]
```

I want to know if there is something more straightforward than this

```
l = []
list.each{ l = l + it }
println l
```

like a default groovy closure or method?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try [`flatten`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#flatten%28%29), ie:

```
list.flatten()
```

Or, to get the output you want:

```
list = [[1,2,3], [6], [3,4,5,6]]

assert list.flatten().sort() == [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6]
```

Comment: Note that the semantics of this are different in that it recurses through the lists, producing different results in situations like this: `[[1,2,3], [4,[5]],[6]].flatten()`. The cleanest way of doing the OP's concatenation is `list.collectMany { it }`.

Comment: @Desty that should be a new answer

Answer (score 6):

As some people may miss the comment by @Desty, posted as answer here:

> Note that the semantics of this are different in that it recurses
> through the lists, producing different results in situations like
> this: [[1,2,3], [4,[5]],[6]].flatten(). The cleanest way of doing the
> OP's concatenation is list.collectMany { it }

Example:

```
list = [[1,2,3], [6], [3,4,5,6]]
assert list.collectMany{ it }.sort() == [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6]
```

Comment: One advantage is that `collectMany` keeps the object type correctly, while with `flatten` reports `List<?>` as result, which you may need to cast it to prevent IDE errors/warnings.